# Use group by function on column without mentioning column name in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I want to use group by function on column name `msg_type` in table `prod_replay_in` but do not want to use column name `msg_type` in below query. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
Table name = prod_replay_in
Column list =  id int,
               msg_type varchar(20), 
               msg  text;
```

**What I have tried?**

```
select count(*), msg_type from prod_replay_in
group by msg_type
```

Comment: Not clear why you do not want to use column name. SQL is a declarative language where explicit commands are sent to query engine. If you need dynamic querying, use application layer (Java, Python, PHP) or procedural code (pgsql).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window` functions to compute aggregate results without using `GROUP BY` clause.

Sample SQL -

```
select t.msg_type, t.ccount from
(select msg_type, count(*) over(partition by msg_type) ccount, 
rank() over(partition by msg_type order by id) rrank 
from prod_replay_in) t where rrank = 1;
```